# A value of type "*const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"

Tags: c++, string, malloc

So I am trying to avoid using strings for this. I am basically trying to make a string array.

```
char **hourtimes = (char**)malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        (*hourtimes) = (char*)malloc((100 * sizeof(char)));
    }
```

So I made a string array basically here

Now, I want to make `hourtimes[0] = "twelve"`;

I tried doing `*hourtimes = "twelve";`

but I get the same error, I think this works in c, but I'm using c++

`hourtimes[0][0] = 't';`
`hourtimes[0][1] = 'w';`

etc works just fine but that would be too cumbersome

Comment: `(*hourtimes)` you forgot to index it as `hourtimes[i]` in the memory allocation. You keep over-writing the previous pointer.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned you're using C++ rather than C.  You should have tagged C++ instead, in that case, or you'll get a bunch of answers from us C people assuming you're using C.

Comment: If you're using C++, why is the question tagged C, and why are you using `malloc` instead of `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: ***I think this works in c, but I'm using c++*** This is what the basis of your problem is. You are thinking of `c` solutions and trying to get them to work in `c++` instead of using `c++`

Answer (score 4):

`*hourtimes = "twelve"` is setting `*hourtimes` to point to an immutable string literal.  You are then trying to modify that immutable string.  What you want to do is copy "twelve" into *hourtimes.

```
strcpy(hourtimes[0],"twelve");
```

**Note:** This answer was written at a time when the question was tagged for C. C++ will have different preferred ways of doing this kind of thing.

Comment: The C++ (and C)  Standard doesn't say anything about "Read Only Memory", and very rarl;y will string literals be stored in ROM, though they may be stored in memory that detects writes after a program has loaded. Both standards do say that attempting to modify a string literal is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Use `strncpy()` instead to avoid a buffer overflow when copying large strings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If you are positive that the string will fit in your buffer, there is no point in wasting compute cycles with the "safe" version.  In this case the buffer is 100 bytes, and the string being copied is... significantly less.  Otherwise, if we are going to assume it could possibly not fit, we'd have to perform more checks to ensure safety than just using `strncpy`.  Gotta check the last character to see if it is a NULL-terminated and then decide what course of action to take if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong: You can't assign a `const char *` to a `char *`. What does that mean, though?

Both `const char *` and `char *` are types. They are, in fact, very nearly the same type; one is a pointer to a character, and the other is a pointer to a *constant* character. That means that the latter can't be changed<sup>1</sup>; that's, after all, what "constant" means. So when you try to tell the compiler to treat a pointer to a constant type as a pointer to a non-`const` type, it'll give you an error -- because otherwise it'd have no way to guarantee that the string isn't modified.

`"whatever"` is always a `const char *`, not a `char *`, because that's stored in memory that's generally not meant to be modified, and the compiler can make some *really neat* optimizations if it can safely assume that it's unchanged (which, because it's `const`, it can).

I won't tell you how to "properly" write the code you're going for, because if you're using C++, you should be using `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of anything with pointers whenever possible, and that probably includes here. If, for whatever reason, you *need* to use pointers, the comments have covered that well enough.

---

<sup>1: Okay, yes, it can -- but that's outside the scope of this answer, and I don't want to confuse any beginners.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In your allocation loop, `(*hourtimes)` is the same as `hourtimes[0]`, so you are assigning your allocated sub-arrays to the same slot in the main array on each loop iteration, causing memory leaks and uninitialized slots.  You need to use `hourtimes[i]` instead:

```
char **hourtimes = (char**)malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    hourtimes[i] = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
}
```

And don't forget to deallocate the arrays when you are done with them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    free(hourtimes[i]);
}

free(hourtimes);
```

Now, a string literal has type `const char[N]`, where `N` is the number of characters in the literal, + 1 for the null terminator.  So `"twelve"` would be a `const char[7]`.

Your arrays only allow `char*` pointers to be stored, but a `const char[N]` decays into a `const char*` pointer to the first `char`.  You can't assign a `const char*` to a `char*`, thus the compiler error.

Even if it were possible to do (which it is, but only with a type-cast), you *shouldn't* do it, because doing so would cause a memory leak as you would lose your original pointer to the allocated array, and worse `free()` can't deallocate a string literal anyway.

What you really want to do is copy the *content* of the string literal into the allocated array storage.  You can use `strncpy()` for that:

```
strncpy(hourtimes[0], "twelve", 100);
```

Now, with all of that said, this is the C way of handling arrays of strings.  The C++ way is to use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> hourtimes(100);
...
hourtimes[0] = "twelve";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a string literal, which can be used as a pointer to a constant `char`, but not as a pointer to a non-const char.

```
"twelve"
```

You do however attempt to assign it to a pointer to non-const char.

```
hourtimes[0] = "twelve";
```

That is what the compiler does not like.